# Vuex - function in "watch" not firing if "null" is committed in store action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, reactive-programming

i am having a problem trying to update some template properties if a Vuex store value changes

when i'm setting the value to `undefined` inside my store action (for example `commit('SET_SELECTED_TICKET_ATTACHMENTS', undefined);`), everything seems to work fine.

When setting the value to `null` however (`commit('SET_SELECTED_TICKET_ATTACHMENTS', null);`, my watch function will not fire.

The watch function in question looks like this:

```js
selectedTicketAttachments () {
  this.isTicketAttachmentLoading = false;
}
```

The mutation looks like this

```js
SET_SELECTED_TICKET_ATTACHMENTS(state, selectedTicketAttachments){
  state.selectedTicketAttachments = selectedTicketAttachments;
},
```

Any help would me much appreciated!

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The question doesn't make sense without a context. It's safe to assume that selectedTicketAttachments  has already been null, so a watcher won't be triggered for the same value

Comment: @EstusFlask what other information would be helpful to you? I can't accurately reproduce this without creating a relatively large project.

Comment: @EstusFlask i was not able to check it yet, but you might just have been right with your assumption that the value was already null. I'll keep you updated, but your comment has already been a great help. :)

Comment: @EstusFlask you were 100% right. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Glad it was that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as EstusFlask has already mentioned, the commit will not be executed if the state will not be changed. My problem was that, under certain conditions, null will already have been commited at a time at which the execution of my watch handler would have gone unnoticed.